# Displaying Total of spinedit values in a List Box

Tags: lazarus

I am obviously new to Delphi but I just cant seem to figure this simple in  out. I need to be able to click the  button ' Total for the day ' and this should add the 3 spinedit values and display the total in a List Box.

Comment: Please add some code here with what you have tried.

Comment: What you need to do is use your IDE or text editor, and write some code. It's off topic to come here and ask us to do your homework for you.

Comment: Its unnecessary to be rude, I was asking a question just like anyone else here

Comment: The fact that there is no code, and a simple task, implies this is homework. If you had code, you'd have shown it. Did you visit the [help] yet?

Answer (score 1):

I dont have Delphi at hand here so I am not sure if SpinEdit.Value is an integer or not, but this should get you on your way:

```
var
  Total: integer;
begin
  Total := SpinEdit1.Value + SpinEdit2.Value + SpinEdit3.Value;
  // now just display Total wherever you want...
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, thats the code I have and now I just need to display the Total in the Listbox  but its not displaying . Ive done this               Listbox.Items.Add(Total);

Comment: Total in my example is an integer, if you want to display it in a listbox you will have to convert it to s string: Listbox.Items.Add(IntTostr(Total));